# Lollipop on HTC One M8

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to update to Lollipop OTA on my HTC One M8, rooted, S-ON. I've read that it won't work with a custom recovery (I was using CWM) so I flashed a stock recovery and removed SuperSU, and that all seemed well and good but the update still won't apply. It just boots into the recovery menu(?) then stops.

Please help!

Comment: Is there an error message displayed on the recovery menu?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be the "fingerprint": when it blocks in the recovery menu hold "volume up" and "power" buttons some second then release, you should see some error message in the bottom.
This could be an useful guide: http://android-revolution-hd.blogspot.se/2013/12/how-to-manually-install-ota-update.html